JavaScript how to log the value a user has put in?
The problem given was:
When the user clicks the button with the ID of generate-message, log the value the user has typed into the input field.
Here is the HTML provided:
 <input type="text" id="message">
 <button id="generate-message">Express Yourself!</button>

I have tried multiple things, my most recent attempt was:
 const button = document.getElementId("generate-message")
 button.addEventListener("click", function(){
 })


It looks like your attempt stopped right before you try to... log the value a user has put in.  Where are you stuck?  You appear to know how to select an element from the DOM based on its id.  Have you tried selecting that input element?  Have you tried reading a .value property from that element?  Have you tried logging that value somewhere?

So, if button references a DOM ButtonElement, you already know how to cache Elements (by ID) from the DOM. Do the same for your InputElement with ID of message. Than, inside the event handler function get  that Input value. Google: "how to get an input element value". If you don't know how to log things, google: "how to use console in JavaScript".

Dan P. said "You will likely have been getting errors using the wrong function name." — you can see those errors in the browser console. In both Chrome and Firefox you can open the Developer Tools by pressing F12 and you will see the console with any error messages at the bottom of the window that opens. Learning to use the browser console and the debugger are essential skills.

Welcome to StackOverflow!
You're first attempt was a good start!
Firstly, the function to get an element by it's ID is getElementById, not getElementId. You will likely have been getting errors using the wrong function name.
Once you have the button's event listener set up, you can put whatever code inside it you like. You can use functions like console.log() or alert() to see the contents of a variable.
Have a good go at it yourself, but if you are really struggling, here's how you could do it:


const button = document.getElementById("generate-message")
 const input = document.getElementById("message")
 
 button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  const val = input.value;
  console.log(val);
  alert("Your value is: " + val)
 })
<input type="text" id="message">
<button id="generate-message">Express Yourself!</button>




This is such a spoiler. At least you've could explained in general lines where to focus the attention and hide the snippet... Anyways...

@RokoC.Buljan I didn't clock that this seems to be a homework task, and not just someone learning JS. I've hidden the snippet and given some suggestions of what they can do to get some output in their code.
